# Android app using Proguard & R8 differences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, proguard

In my android app i am using `Google R8`(experimental release for now) and `Proguard 6.0.3` ...
According to your experience, what do you think ? What is the main difference ?
With `R8` my app is smaller in size and the speed of process compared to `Proguard` is really much better. Number of classes when using `R8` are smaller comparing to `Proguard`.

R8 is compatible with existing Proguard rules , but it ignore some like :

```
Ignoring option: -optimizationpasses"
Ignoring option: -assumenoexternalreturnvalues"
Ignoring option: -assumenoexternalsideeffects"
```

it gives just warning too for missing classes not errors for example :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: org.dbunit.dataset.datatype.DefaultDataTypeFactory","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.inmobi.ads.InMobiNative$NativeAdListener","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: javax.enterprise.util.AnnotationLiteral","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: sun.net.www.protocol.http.Handler","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: com.flurry.android.ads.FlurryAdNativeListener","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: sun.net.spi.nameservice.NameServiceDescriptor","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class: java.lang.ClassValue","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

So in general i think that `R8` is much better than `Proguard` regardless for the fact that it is still experimental version.

Google say :

> R8 is a Proguard replacement for whole program minification and
> optimization.

and i think this is really true.

But how this tools works in details ? What makes main the difference between each other and how the R8 works in deep ?

> UPDATE :

After update to Android Studio 3.3 Canary 2 , when using R8 seems that size of APK doesn't have any difference from using Proguard

p.s : sorry for my English :) :) :)

> UPDATE (14-MAR-2019) :

Latest R8 version for the moment `V. 1.4.71` seems really good, faster than Proguard and when comparing generated Apk/Bundle from R8, the size is smaller. Also DEX method counts are smaller too.
I am using R8 Shrinker in production and everything seems very promising. Great Job really.

> UPDATE (08-APRIL-2019) :

Latest R8 version for the moment `V. 1.4.79` seems really good, faster than Proguard and when comparing generated Apk/Bundle from R8, the size is smaller. Also DEX method counts are smaller too.
I am using R8 Shrinker in production and everything seems very promising. Great Job really.

Comment: I have the `Missing class: java.lang.ClassValue` warning/error too, but I don't use what you used. Should I ignore it? What does it mean? Is it an issue? I added `-dontwarn java.lang.ClassValue` just to ignore it.

Comment: where did u add this line , please tell in detail, i am getting error while buidling signed apk, plz help